# No files were found with the provided path: build. No artifacts will be uploaded. - Github Action for deploying React App to Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, github-actions

I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kLEp5tGDqcI) tutorial on setting up CI/CD with github actions for a react app. I want the action to build and deploy my react app to my firebase project for hosting. I'm fairly sure I'm followed the directions, but when I trigger my action with a push, I get this error:

```
> Run actions/download-artifact@v2   
> with:
>     name: build
>     path: build Starting download for build Error: Unable to find any artifacts for the associated workflow
```

```yml
# This workflow will do a clean install of node dependencies, build the source code and run tests across different versions of node
# For more information see: https://help.github.com/actions/language-and-framework-guides/using-nodejs-with-github-actions

name: Firebase CI

on: push 

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x]
        # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/f

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    - run: npm ci
    - name: Archive Build
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: build
        path: build
        
  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Download Build
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: build
          path: build
      - name: Deploy to Firebase
        uses: w9jds/firebase-action@master
        with:
          args: deploy --only hosting
        env:
          FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}
```

I can install, build, and deploy manually from my console just fine. I thought this error might have something to do with my build directory's location, but its in the standard place. Any thoughts on what this might be?

Link to the full repo [here](https://github.com/wyhinton/DIYCartographyDisplay)

Additional Screenshots:

[image: Action results]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like removing `/build` from my .gitignore solved the problem. I'm not %100 sure why though, as none of the examples of similar actions I have seen include their build folders.

Comment: Are you checking in an updated `/build` directory with every release build?

Comment: Same question, although my problem has also been fixed by removing /build/ from .gitignore file but pushing build folder to branch literally sounds like forcing 12 years old kid to handle segfault error. Also, pushing new build to branch every time takes so much long time to commit. Don't know, whether it's a correct way or not?